# Can I add a credit/debit card to PayPal that's under someone else's name?

Tags: paypal

My girlfriend would like to add her debit card to my PayPal so that we just have one PayPal that has both mine and her cards, and it would be easier because we live at the same address.

Unfortunately, when I go to "Add Credit Card or Debit Card," it has an option to change the card owner's *first* name but not the last name. She does not have the same last name as I do.

Is there anything I can do to add a card under her name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to change the last name directly.

PayPal is very specific about you owning the card since on-line credit card fraud is quite a big problem. Since this information is passed to the bank when purchasing, they do verify each transaction.

You could take a chance and load it anyway, and check if it will work that way. Since it's only the last name that will differ some banks ignore it since it may be a case of someone changing their last name or getting married for example. I know this is the case with some on-line payment system I have implemented in the past.